# You have an error in your SQL syntax that i cannot seem to resolve

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group, name, domain, status) VALUES ('19', 'Minecraft', 'Bukkit', 'Bukkit Basic'' at line 1

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (id, server, group, name, domain, status)
VALUES ('".$productid."', '".$productserver."', '".$productgroup."',
'".$productname."', '".$productdomain."', '".$productstatus."')")
OR die(mysql_error());
```

I have rewritten the code 5 times.

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_query` or anything else in the unsupported and now deprecated MySQL extension?

Comment: What do you recommend then?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. **Why are you using the MySQL extension?** I want to know where people (especially new PHP devs) are getting this information? As for what you should be using, the PDO and MySQLi extensions are the currently maintained MySQL client extensions

Comment: When i learned PHP for about 3 years ago i watched PhpMyAcademy, I asked my friends who were expirienced.    For me Mysql_query works just fine.. I dont see any problems

Comment: There's been a large warning on all the MySQL extension manual pages for much  longer than 3 years. Also, did you mean https://phpacademy.org/ ?

Comment: Yes, however.. What is wrong with MySQL extension.. I mean if there is a security hole I will obviously switch right away.. But if it isnt.. There is no hurry is it?

Comment: There may well be security holes in the MySQL extension (I haven't checked the bug list). It is after all, unmaintained. The most important part is that it does not give you the tools to write secure code (namely prepared statements and parameter binding). Your queries are subject to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Using `mysql_real_escape_string` is simply not a viable solution to SQL safety.

Comment: I will look into MySQLi I suppose

Comment: I now use MySQLi.. Happy? :) $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO products (id, userid, server, `group`, name, domain, status) VALUES ('".$productid."', '".$_SESSION['id']."', '".$productserver."', '".$productgroup."', '".$productname."', '".$productdomain."', '".$productstatus."')");

Comment: No. Use prepared statements and parameter binding

Comment: Show me what you would like then, im open to learn new things all the time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`group` is a reserved word in MySQL. You have to escape it with backticks:

```
INSERT INTO products (id, server, `group`, name, domain, status) VALUES ...
```

Answer (score 2):

use backticks (`) around column names when you use reserved keywords in query. `group` is a reserved keyword. So use `group`

See [Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)